# ffmpeg batch image generation with multiple images

Tags: php, image, batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I'm currently generating images of a video every X seconds (in this case, 1 image every minute). I have a command line that works perfectly, but I would like to make it work on batches of videos as opposed to each video individually. Is this possible? I've used PHP scripts on a batch of videos to generate one image at X seconds, but I'd like more than one image per video.

This is the command line that I use on individual videos:

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60 -b:v 64k OUTPUT-%05d.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Bash:

```
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i ${file} -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/60 -b:v 64k ${file}-%05d.jpg; done
```

This will take each file in the current directory with an extension of `.mp4` and call the ffmpeg command on it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I navigated to the necessary directory and ran the above command but it did not work. I got "no such file or directory" for each file, so it would say "smash-into-darkness.mp4.mp4: No such file or directory" Any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: I just got it to work. I had to remove the .mp4 after the ${file} for the input, it works. Thank you!!

Comment: @user3597867 Oops sorry for the typo, glad you got it working. For posterity: the code above is now correct.